# Subroutines with non-contiguous address space in ARM ELF

Tags: arm, elf, disassembly

In disassembly, it's desirable to identify start and end address of each subroutine. One problem that arise in x86 (not 100% sure) is that the address space of subroutines might be non-contiguous. So far, I couldn't find such subroutines in ARM disassembly.

Do subroutines in ARM ELF <s>**always**</s> typically  occupy a contiguous address space?

**UPDATE**:

I'm interested in static analysis of binaries. For any static analysis to **scale** while maintaining **precision**  it should rely on reasonable assumptions. For a function that consists of a set of basic blocks BB_1, if it jumps to another set of basic blocks BB_2, that are far away in memory, we can *pessimistically* consider BB_2 as another function for our purposes. However, if we can identify BB_2 as a set of basic blocks that adhere to common *idiom*, e.g., clean-up. That can make a difference. Therefore, it would be very useful if such idioms are identified together with how they are used in practice.

Comment: It's not so much  a question of the ISA as of what generated the code. You can do all manner of crazy things in hand-written assembly if you so wish, on pretty much any ISA. If a really clever optimising compiler can generate something tricky (e.g. multiple functions all branching to some common cleanup/epilogue code) for x86, it can do it for pretty much any other ISA it supports.

Comment: @Notlikethat IDA Pro supports function "chunks" which means that the issue is confirmed at least in X86(_64). I'm aware that the lay out of functions in memory is irrelevant as far as the processor is concerned. Hence, compilers are, in principle, free to do what ever they which.  However, it might be the case that ARM has some rule somewhere to discourage (or even prohibit) such practice. If you are aware of any such rule please provide it in an answer and I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: GCC can split up functions into hot and cold sections, keeping all the hot sections close together. It can also do partial inlining where in only inlines part of a function. That may end up creating two different versions of the same function.

Comment: Again, there is nothing ARM or X86 or MIPS or most other ISA's in this class that would limit you, I would think x86 most limiting.  This is all about the compiler, not the ISA.  And looking at how one version one one compiler works on one host is interesting but you cannot draw any conclusions of any kind.  And even if you examined all of the compilers available at this moment, your research could/would be invalid shortly thereafter.

Comment: Your analysis tool has to define for itself what a function is and it does not have to correlate to what the high level language sources define a function as.  You need to just start your analysis with as many different compiled binaries you care to find, and then as each new problem comes along that breaks your tool you adapt.  There is nothing you can do ahead of time to prevent that, it will and will continue to happen.  completely independent of ISA.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any "such rule" but you should really start with defining what you call start and end of subroutine in the context of disassembly.
As @Notlikethat mentioned already - there are such things as epilogue/clean-up, generated by compiler and/or linker - do you consider them part of the subroutine? There is no easy answer here.
On an ARM platform it is very common to use 'veneers'(spelling? lazy to check) to ensure the correct ARM/Thumb interworking - would you consider them being part of a subroutine? They can definitely be miles apart in the memory.

**UPD.**

> Do subroutines in ARM ELF typically occupy a contiguous address space?

In my experience (with gcc toolchains) the short answer is:
Yes - if gcc optimization is turned off.
But if the optimization is On - you can not rely on this at all.
A modern optimizing compiler/linker is allowed to do any 'dirty' tricks that it feels appropriate .. and it does.
In the context of your question - nothing prevents it from detecting a common part of code in two (or more) functions and re-organize the code to jump to that part and thus avoid code duplication.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I agree that there is no easy definition of a "function". A good start would be that any basic block reachable by "others" **only** through function entry (prologue) shall be considered as part of a function. However, It would help here if we can establish that having a contiguous address space is the "rule" and start from there by quantifying exceptions to that rule. So far, veneers and clean-up epilogue are clear exceptions.

Comment: @Oxcode I think it would be much easier for everyone if you stated the ultimate purpose of your question. I have a feeling that if you do this me (and others) would be able steer away from irrelevant theoretical concepts and get to the point much quicker. ;)  So far, you mentioned disassembly, ARM, ELF and 'subroutine'/'function', you also refer to some x86 non-contiguousity problem, which I cannot comment on as I've never worked with x86 on low level. The topic remains too broad.. That is, if we are on "assembly" level - there is simply no such thing as 'function' (ARM), so the rest is moot:)